# Scala: Applying a linear operation on all elements of an ArrayBuffer, and also checking bounds

Tags: list, scala, arraybuffer

My question is a two-parter.

### Part 1

I have an `ArrayBuffer` of tuples `(x,y)`. I have a tuple, `(deltaX,deltaY)`, which can look like `(-1,0)` (as an example) to designate the change to apply to all tuples of the `ArrayBuffer`.

In Python it would be something like:

```
newBuffer = [(x+deltaX,y+deltaY) for x,y in oldBuffer]
```

### Part 2

Is there a way to check a conditional on all the items in the `ArrayBuffer`? In my case I wish to ensure all coordinates are within bounds, so something like (to again use the Python equivalent):

```
if all(0<=x<xBound and 0<=y<yBound for x,y in buffer)
```

I can do all these things with lots of very long and annoying code but I am wondering if there is a smarter way.

Comment: A look through http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer would have quickly answered both questions. If you're not yet familiar with the API scaladoc, you should be!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is a simple `map`:

```
val (dx, dy) = (-1, 0)
val (xBound, yBound) = (4, 3)
val tuples = Array(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 0)

tuples.map { case (x, y) => (x + dx, y + dy) }
```

And the second one is a use of `exists` or `forall`:

```
tuples.exists { case (x, y) => x >= xBound || y >= yBound }
tuples.forall { case (x, y) => x < xBound && y < yBound }
```

You might also want to use `filter` and then check `isEmpty`, or `nonEmpty`:

```
tuples.filter { case (x, y) => x < xBound && y < yBound }.isEmpty
tuples.filter { case (x, y) => x >= xBound || y > yBound }.nonEmpty
```

Scala has many syntactic alternatives that you may come across.  Here are some examples:

```
tuples.map(tuple => (tuple._1 + dx) -> (tuple._2 + dy))
tuples forAll { tuple =>
    val (x, y) = tuple
    x < xBound && y < yBound
}
tuples.filter(_._1 < xBound).filter(_._2 < yBound).isEmpty

for { (x, y) <- tuples } yield (x + dx, y + dy)

(for {
    (x, y) <- tuples
    if x < xBound
    if y < yBound
} yield (x, y)).isEmpty
```

Comment: To clarify, the second question is about asking a boolean condition, not filtering a list for valid points (I am checking to see if any points are out of bounds if I move a certain direction). Although the information you've posted so far is still very useful to know about filters!

Comment: Is there any performance difference in using exists vs. forall, or filter + isEmpty? I'm assuming exists is probably faster because it (again, assuming) short-circuits the instant it finds a condition that meets the parameters?

Comment: @user5063423 In the general case, you're intuition is definitely correct.  However, some collections are lazy (e.g. `Stream`, `Iterator`), and then the approaches could be equivalent.  Using `withFilter` or `view` on the list could also enable this type of lazy, short-circuiting logic.